# Linear Equation in 2 variables (Concept)

Tags: linear-algebra

$$ 6x + 8y = 1  -(1)$$
$$ 26x + 48y=5 -(2)$$

We can solve this by multiplying *(1)* with *6* :
$$36x+48y=6 -(3)$$
$$26x+48y=5-(4)$$
Gives, $$x=0.1$$

Now substituting this on *(1)* gives me *y* too. But, what exactly happened here? Well, I'm trying to understand this differently. How can we do this? Plotting *(1)* and *(2)* on a graph give both *x & y*. But plotting *(3)* and *(4)* makes no difference. But *y* in *(3) & (4)* could take any value?

Comment: $y$ in equation (3) can take any value, the same for equation (4). But if you solve these equations simultaneously, $y$ can take only value corresponding to intersection point of lines, described by equations.

Comment: There is no difference between plot of equation (1) and equation (3) because these equations are equivalent. The reason of multiplying is not related to plotting, but to possibility of removal of $y$-part by subtracting. It is like searching for weight of fruits in puzzle: 6 apples and 8 pears weight 1 kg, 26 apples and 48 pears weight 5 kg. Every apple weight is the same and every pear weight is the same. To exclude pears we can multiply first part by 6 and get 36 apples and 48 pears weight 6 kg, then 10 apples weight 1 kg and so on.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Exactly, but is there something so fundamental about this subtracting? How is it even possible in the first place? Like something seems off. What I meant is like the divisibility rules. We can find stuff that could explain the phenomena when we dig deep.

Comment: When you subtract, you lose information about $y$, so you need to save at least one of two equations for following use. $\begin{cases} 6x+8y=1\\ 26x+48y=5\end{cases}\Rightarrow$ $\begin{cases} 36x+48y=6\\ 26x+48y=5\end{cases} \Rightarrow$  $\begin{cases} 10x=1\\ 48y=5-26x\end{cases} \Rightarrow$ $\begin{cases} x=0.1\\ 48y=5-26\cdot 0.1\end{cases} \Rightarrow$ $\begin{cases} x=0.1\\ 48y=2.4\end{cases} \Rightarrow$ $\begin{cases} x=0.1\\ y=0.05\end{cases}$.

Answer (score 1):

You made a mistake when you substituted $x=0.1$ into the prior equation...$y$ is not $0.1$ but $0.05.$

$$6(0.1) + 8y = 1 \\ .6 + 8y = 1 \\ 8y = 0.4 \\ y = 0.05$$

If you took the two values for $x$ and $y$ we found and put them into the second equation...

$$26(0.1) + 48(0.05) \stackrel{?} = 5 \\ 2.6 + 2.4 \stackrel {?}= 5 \\ 5 = 5 \checkmark$$

Thus, the only values that could satisfy your equation would be $$x = 0.1 \\ y=0.05$$